# Wordpress not showing sup/sub in post via editor only

Tags: css, wordpress

I am making a WP theme from scratch and have used a CSS Reset. I have therefore recoded my sup and sub tags, and these work fine on my site. Here is an example:

```css
sup,
sub {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  line-height: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

sup {
  top: -0.5em
}

sub {
  bottom: -0.25em;
}
```

```html
H<sub>2</sub>O (aq) + NaCl (s) → H<sub>2</sub>O (aq) + Na<sup>+</sup> (aq) + Cl<sup>-</sup> (aq)
```

Now this works perfectly as shown both here and when I manually enter it as pure html on my site. However, when adding it through a post via 'the_excerpt()' (for example), it simply shows:

H2O (aq) + NaCl (s) → H2O (aq) + Na+ (aq) + Cl– (aq)

Here is a screen-cap of my code:
[image: my code]

And this is the result:
[image: my resulting display]

I know it's a problem with my theme, as when I use the built in 'Twenty Twenty' theme it works fine.

So I guess my questions are: what is wordpress doing to my post that's stopping my custom css for sup and sub from working? And how do I fix it?

Comment: how are you setting the excerpt?

Comment: Ah! This got me to check, thanks!
I was simply allowing WP to garner the first few lines of code as it does by default. When I manually added code to the 'Excerpt' section in the editor it displayed properly!